# to get the time difference between the time in different timezone for my wp7 App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i would like to get the time difference between the time in different timezone for my wp7 App.I have tried to convert both of the time to UTC. But I cant convert the time in another zone.Ican convert system's time only.I am getting the input time with timwzone(for eg: 2012-03-09, 3:02AM PST).Please give me the solution As early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, starting off with the local time is problematic - because a local time can be ambiguous (or even invalid). You'd need to decide what to do in that situation.

Once you've got a UTC time, you can call [`TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396378%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on both time zones, and subtract one offset from the other.

In terms of the original conversion to UTC... you can call `GetUtcOffset` with the "local" `DateTime` (by which I mean a `DateTime` with a Kind of `Unspecified`, *not* `Local`), then create a `DateTime` by subtracting the offset from the local time, and making the kind `Utc`. Note that the `GetUtcOffset` call assumes standard time if the local time is ambiguous.

Of course, before you do *any* of this, you need to get the relevant `TimeZoneInfo` objects for your two time zones. Do you have those? If you could say exactly what your input values and types are, and how you want to handle ambiguity, I could probably whip up a method to do this... (I'd prefer to do it in my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library, but that isn't available in Silverlight yet...)

Comment: Hi Jon,My Pblm still not solved.Can u tell me how can we convert client side time( for example: Date: 2012-03-12, 2:37AM PDT)to UTC or to local time.Actually my Pblm is to take the difference between client side time and local system's time both are in defferent timezone.

Comment: @ishaan: You haven't provided any more information though, which means I can't really give you any more help. What have you tried, what are your requirements etc?